# JEditorPane.getPreferredSize not always working in Java 9?

Tags: java, swing, java-9, jeditorpane, preferredsize

This question is about different behaviour of `JEditorPane` in Java 8 and Java 9. I’d like to know if others have experienced the same, whether it could be a bug in Java 9, and if possible have your input to how to handle it in Java 9.

Context: In our (age-old) code base we are using a subclass of `JTable`, and for rendering multi-line HTML in one of the columns we are using a subclass of `JEditorPane`. We are using `JEditorPane.getPreferredSize()` for determining the height of the content and using it for setting the height of the table row. It’s been working well for many years. It doesn’t work in Java 9; the rows are displayed just 10 pixels high. Seen both on Windows and Mac.

I should like to show you two code examples. If the first and shorter one suffices for you, feel free to skip the second and longer one.

MCVE:

```
JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");

pane.setText("<html>One line</html>");
System.out.println(pane.getPreferredSize());
pane.setText("<html>Line one<br />Line 2<br />Third line<br />Line four</html>");
System.out.println(pane.getPreferredSize());
```

Output in Java 8 (1.8.0_131):

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=48,height=15]
java.awt.Dimension[width=57,height=60]
```

And on Java 9 (jdk-9.0.4):

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=49,height=15]
java.awt.Dimension[width=58,height=0]
```

In Java 9 the first time I set the text, the preferred height reflects it. Every subsequent time it doesn’t.

I have searched to see if I could find any information on a bug that might account for this, did not find anything relevant.

**Question: Is this intended (change of) behaviour? Is it a bug??**

### Longer example

```
public class TestJEditorPaneAsRenderer extends JFrame {

    public TestJEditorPaneAsRenderer() {
        super("Test JEditorPane");
        
        MyRenderer renderer = new MyRenderer();
        
        String html2 = "<html>one/2<br />two/2</html>";
        String html4 = "<html>one of four<br />two of four<br />"
                + "three of four<br />four of four</html>";
        JTable table = new JTable(new String[][] { { html2 }, { html4 } },
                                  new String[] { "Dummy col title" }) {
            @Override
            public TableCellRenderer getDefaultRenderer(Class<?> colType) {
                return renderer;
            }
        };
        
        add(table);
        setSize(100, 150);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        new TestJEditorPaneAsRenderer().setVisible(true);
    }

}

class MyRenderer extends JEditorPane implements TableCellRenderer {

    public MyRenderer() {
        super("text/html", "");
    }
    
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        setText(value.toString());
        Dimension preferredSize = getPreferredSize();
        System.out.format("Row %d preferred size %s%n",row, preferredSize);
        if (preferredSize.height > 0 && table.getRowHeight(row) != preferredSize.height) {
            table.setRowHeight(row, preferredSize.height);
        }
        return this;
    }
    
}
```

Result on Java 8 is as expected:

[image: Java 8 screen shot]

Output from Java 8:

```
1.8.0_131
Row 0 preferred size java.awt.Dimension[width=32,height=30]
Row 1 preferred size java.awt.Dimension[width=72,height=60]
Row 0 preferred size java.awt.Dimension[width=32,height=30]
Row 1 preferred size java.awt.Dimension[width=72,height=60]
```

On Java 9 the second row is not shown high enough so most of the lines are hidden:

[image: Java 9 screen shot showing problem]

Output from Java 9:

```
9.0.4
Row 0 preferred size java.awt.Dimension[width=33,height=30]
Row 1 preferred size java.awt.Dimension[width=73,height=0]
Row 0 preferred size java.awt.Dimension[width=33,height=0]
Row 1 preferred size java.awt.Dimension[width=73,height=0]
```

A possible fix is if I create a new renderer component each time by changing the body of `getDefaultRenderer()` to:

```
return new MyRenderer();
```

Now the table looks good as on Java 8. If necessary I suppose we could live with a similar fix in our production code, but it seems quite a waste. Especially if it’s only necessary until the behaviour change is reverted in a coming Java version. **I’d be grateful for your suggestions here.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have faced similar problem, but with JLabel. My solution was to set the size of the JLabel which seems to force the component to recalculate its preferred size.

Try this:

```
JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");

pane.setText("<html>One line</html>");
System.out.println(pane.getPreferredSize());
pane.setText("<html>Line one<br />Line 2<br />Third line<br />Line four</html>");

// get width from initial preferred size, height should be much larger than necessary
pane.setSize(61, 1000);

System.out.println(pane.getPreferredSize());
```

In this casse the output is

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=53,height=25]
java.awt.Dimension[width=61,height=82]
```

Note: my fonts are different, that is why I get different dimensions.

Edit: I changed your getTableCellRendererComponent in the longer example like this and it is working for me. I am using jdk9.0.4, 64 bit.

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
    setText(value.toString());

    Dimension preferredSize = getPreferredSize();
    setSize(new Dimension(preferredSize.width, 1000));
    preferredSize = getPreferredSize();

    System.out.format("Row %d preferred size %s%n", row, preferredSize);
    if (preferredSize.height > 0 && table.getRowHeight(row) != preferredSize.height) {
        table.setRowHeight(row, preferredSize.height);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Also in our production code. A bit of a hack, maybe, but I certainly prefer it over the wasteful fix I had.

Comment: That looks like the relevant side effect is the `invalidate();` call implied by `setSize(…)`, so just calling `pane.invalidate();` should have the same effect and feel less nasty than modifying the size.

Comment: @Holger I have tried various combinations of `invalidate();`, `validate();`, `revalidate()`, ... and it doesn't change the preferred height. I think that setting the size of the component is important part in this hack. I've also found out that height set with `setHeight` doesn't have to be large it just needs to be larger than initial preferred height.

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous suggestion and digging in JDK sources I'm suggesting a little bit simpler solution:

```
setSize(new Dimention(0, 0))
```

Based on BasicTextUI.getPreferredSize implementation it forces to recalculate root view size

```
            } else if (d.width == 0 && d.height == 0) {
            // Probably haven't been layed out yet, force some sort of
            // initial sizing.
            rootView.setSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
```